# CameraController not starting video recording instantly Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, camera, video-recording

I am trying to play a beep sound with vibration before starting video recording. However, there is a delay for `_cameraController.startVideoRecording()`
to start video recording and this delay is not constant. Each time I try recording the delay is different.
How can I do this in a way that recording starts instantly after the beep sound finishes.
my code:
`Future _handleRecording() async {`
`try {`
`await _audioCache.play(_soundPath);`
`Vibration.vibrate(duration: 350);`
`await _cameraController.startVideoRecording();`
`} catch (e) {`
`throw (e);`
`}`
`}`
I am using camera: ^0.8.1+7 dependency the CameraController class.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is you are calling the startVideoRecording after initiating the play function

You have two options since your audio duration is fixed :

First one is to surround you startVideoRecording with delay like that:

```
Future.delay(Duration(seconds:"You audio time"),(){

await _cameraController.startVideoRecording();
} catch (e) {
throw (e);
}

});
```

and the second one is to check when play finish then call startVideoRecording

Comment: Yes but the problem here is when the audio finished the camera will not start recording immediately because startVideoRecording() has a delay of 1-2 secs before starting to record. We want it to seem like the beep audio sound is an indication that the recording has started.

Comment: Have you tested that on release version ?